# Ember-data embedded objects stored as separate objects

Tags: mongodb, ember.js, ember-data

I was wondering if it would be possible to define a model stored into another one.

I have this kind of structure:

```
Model Contact
    String name
    Model Address (hasMany)
    Model Phone (hasMany)
```

On my backend, addresses and phones are MongoDB's embedded documents contained in a "Contact" document.

And, as long as they are embedded documents, they do not have an id.
And when I am on the Emberjs/data layer, they are -well- loaded with the embedded option (cf. the end of the https://github.com/emberjs/data#one-to-one section) but stored as separate objects and this cause trouble when updating or saving...

Comment: I have pasted this link in emberjs irc channel as i need this solution too.

Comment: Thank you for asking the question on irc!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the RESTadapter...
when you are saving you want to serialize all the relationships embedded?

When you are saving or updating your record pass in the options hash to the toJSON method with

```
{associations: true}
```

Take a look at the unit tests on ember-data for examples:
https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/packages/ember-data/tests/unit/to_json_test.js

```
deepEqual(record.toJSON({ associations: true }),
        { id: 1, name: "Chad", phone_numbers: [{
            id: 7,
            number: '123'
          },
          {
            id: 8,
            number: '345'
          },
          {
            id: 9,
            number: '789'
          }
        ]},
        "association is updated after editing associations array");
});
```

Hope this helps..

Comment: thanks this was very helpful and many thanks for taking out time to explain this solution to me on emberjs IRC channels.

Comment: thanks a lot mspisars, it helps a lot, like brg, I guess we are not alone in experiencing this problem!