# Schemaless design for Ember data in Ember.js

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, ember.js, nosql

We are having schemaless database on MongoDB in Rails. I want to know how to use such a schemaless emberjs data design to integrate with such a design.

I am not able to find any documentation on if this can be achieved or if there is any best practice

Can any one help me with this ?

EDIT:
Question is on how to use EmberJS persistent datastore for a schemaless MongoDB Rails backend.

Answer (score 5):

The first two links below should help. See how the first link is setting **primaryKey: '_id'** to recognize mongodb **_id** and the second link shows how to make **active_model_serializer** gem work with **mongoid**, the gem is ember-core team's recommended gem for working with rails and ember-data :

https://github.com/dagda1/workoutzenith/tree/master/app/models

https://github.com/dagda1/workoutzenith/blob/master/config/initializers/active_model_serializer_mongoid_initializer.rb

If you run into problems with embedded mongodb documents and ember-data, this should solve it:

[Ember-data embedded objects stored as separate objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12068373/ember-data-embedded-objects-stored-as-separate-objects)

Read the link below and also examine the github project:

http://tardate.blogspot.co.uk/2012/03/rails-ember-mongodb-bootstrap.html

https://github.com/evendis/rails-ember-mongo-bootstrap-demo

This is not using rails but nodejs, mongodb and emberjs. The mongodb + emberjs might still be useful to you

https://github.com/abelaska/nodejs-emberjs-mongodb

Comment: I have seen https://github.com/evendis/rails-ember-mongo-bootstrap-demo My issue with schemaless DB is that in the EmberJS model [link](https://github.com/evendis/rails-ember-mongo-bootstrap-demo/blob/master/app/assets/javascripts/app/models/post.js.coffee)  I don't have any pre-defined resourceProperties . So how can we use any thing like ember-rest, ember-data etc.

Answer (score 0):

There is still no clear and scalable solution I see of how to apply Ember to scenario where the Rails backend database like MongoDB stores document of any depth with unknown fields.

There are some ways of normalizing but still with existing REST/REST+DS we may have to write a lot of code to serialize and de serialize.

Take a peek on the discussions:

https://github.com/emberjs/data/issues/53#issuecomment-9196555
https://github.com/emberjs/data/issues/100

If some one finds a better pick, please share with me.

Answer (score -2):

Jus follow the links http://robert-reiz.com/2012/03/05/rails-mongodb-tutorial/, http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Rails+3+-+Getting+Started

Comment: Question is on how to use EmberJS persistent datastore for a schemaless MongoDB Rails backend.